# Hashtable implementation in C and Java

Tags: java, c

In Java, HashMap and Hashtable, both implement map interface and store key/value pairs using hash function and Array/LinkedList implementation.  In C also, Hash table can be implemented using Array/LinkedList functionality but there is no concept of key/value pair like map.

So my question is, whether Hash table implementation in C, similar to Hashtable in Java? or its more closer to HashSet in java (except unique elements only condition)?

Comment: Of course you can represent key/value pairs in C. You'll use `struct` instead of objects, but otherwise it works quite similarly.

Comment: Honestly, I don't get the point? In C you can have recursive data structure with structs. In java those data structures and collections are just abstractions for recursive data structure in C.

Comment: Thanks @El. ... actually in Java for HashMap & Hashtable, it store as key and value pair in nodes which is of course just abstraction as compare to data structure in C or in general for Data structure. I guess in Java, for Hashtable, hashing would be done on key's and for HashSet, hashing would be done on values, where as in C, for Hash Table implementation, it can be implemented using struct based on requirements (not part of standard library) if we need to store key/value pair or just values.

Comment: I am familiar enough with java and collections but politely I mean such a thing is pointless

Answer (score 1):

Both semantics (`Hashtable` and `HashSet`) can be implemented in C, but neither comes in the Standard C library. You can find many different has table implementation on the Internet, each with its own advantages and drawbacks. Implementing this yourself may prove difficult as there are many traps and pitfalls.

Answer (score 0):

I previously used BSD's Red-Black trees implementation. It's relatively easy to use when you start to understand how it works.

The really great thing about is that you only have to copy one header file and then just include that where it's needed, no need to link to libraries.

It has similar functionallity to `HashSet`s, you can find by keys with the `RB_FIND()` macro, enumerate elements with `RB_FOREACH()`, insert new ones with `RB_INSERT()` and so on.

You can find more info [in it's MAN page](https://man.dragonflybsd.org/?command=tree&section=3) or the [source code itself](https://github.com/DragonFlyBSD/DragonFlyBSD/blob/master/sys/sys/tree.h).

Answer (score 0):

The difference (in Java) between a `HashTable` and a `HashSet` is in how the key is selected to calculate its hash value. In the `HashSet` the key is the instance stored itself, and the `hashCode()` method is applied to the complete instance, (`Object` provides both, `hashCode()` and `equals(Object)` methods.  In the case of an external key, the `equals(Object)` and `hashCode()` are selected now from the separate key instance, instead of from the stored data value.  For that reason, `HashTable` is normally a subclass of `HashSet` (and every Java table is actually derived from its corresponding `*Set` counterpart), by publishing an internal implementation of the `Map.Entry<K,V>` interface)

Implementing a hash table in C is not too difficult, but you need to understand first what's the key (if external) and the differences between the Key and the Value, the differences between calculating a `hashCode()` and comparing for equality, how are you going to distinguish the key from the value, and how do you manage internally keys and hashes, in order to manage collisions.

I recently started an implementation of a hash table in C (not yet finished) and my `hash_table` constructor need to store in the instance record a pointer to an equals comparison routine (to check for equality, the same as Java requires an `Object`'s `compareTo()` method, this allows you to detect collisions (when you have two entries with the same hash but they compare as different)  and the hash function used on keys to get the hash.  In my implementation probably I will store the full hash value returned by the hash function (before fitting it on the table's size), so I can grow the table in order to simplify the placement of the elements in the new hash table once growed, without having to recalculate all hashes again.

I don't know if this hints can be of help to you, but it's my two cents. :)

My implementation uses a prime numbers table to select the capacity (aprox, doubling the size on each entry) to redimension the table when the number of collisions begin to be unacceptable (whatever this means to you, I have no clear idea yet, this is a time consuming operation, but happens scarcely, so it must be carefully specified, and it is something that Java's `HashTable` does)  But if you don't plan to grow your hash table, or to do it manually, the implementation is easier (just add the number of entries in the constructor parameter list, and create some `grow_hash_table(new_cap)` method.)

Comment: Thanks for the details @Luis Colorado . Its helpful. Though I couldn't understand one point re "HashTable is normally a subclass of HashSet". I guess in Java, Hashtable extends Dictionary class and implements Map interface so not sure about HashSet or Set.

Comment: Well, just checked and both, TreeMap and HashMap, both have nothing in common with TreeSet and HashSet.  I was talking from memory as I remember have seen maps being derived from sets (Think that a Set has only the Key -- that acts as the value) so to derive a map from a set was easy (just add the V value instance to the slot)  But I was wrong, HashMap derives from Dictionary and HashSet from AbstractSet (both derive from Object) And similar for TreeMap and TreeSet.